# How to implement addition and removal of hashtags

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I need to implement something like this:

[image]

The hashtag entry area needs to work like this:
You start a link with a # already there. You can not delete this #. You type in your hashtag, which must not contain any spaces. When you type a space it “enters” the hashtag. This puts a grey box around it with an X button icon. This shows an entered hashtag. If you tap the X it will delete the tag and all the type will move to the left.
After typing the space it moves a space to the right of the boxed hashtag and again starts with the #, so you never have to type a # when creating a tag.

I know how to do this using UITextView, - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView, TTTAttributedLabel, but this is quite a bit of work. I want to see if others have solved this before in a more simple and elegant manner.

Is there an off-the-shelf library for doing this?

The way I thought about solving this is to have a TTTAttributedLabel that can link to all the hashtags. There is a UITapGestureRecognizer attached to the TTTAttributedLabel, so that if no hashtag is pressed, it triggers a UITextView that sits behind the TTTAttributedLabel to display the keyboard. The UITextView is populated with spaces to move the type indicator to the correct position. This is all a lot of work though - was wondering if someone had a neater solution.

Comment: Please include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) in your post. You might also want to add a language related tag

Comment: I know how to do this using UITextView, - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView, TTTAttributedLabel, but this is quite a bit of work. I want to see if others have solved this before.

Comment: SO is not a site where we will just give you the code. Tell us what you tried and why it didn’t work. Than we will see what we can do. If I see your reputation you should know this though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here it is:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.post = [UITextView new];
      self.post.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
      self.post.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
      self.post.frame = Frame(304,250,734,458);
      //  message.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
      self.post.delegate = self;
      self.post.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AauxProOT-Regular" size:Normalize(40)];
    //  self.post.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(73/255.0) green:(73/255.0) blue:(73/255.0) alpha:1];
      self.post.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      self.post.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeTwitter;
      [self.view addSubview:self.post];
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
  if (self.post.text.length == 0)
  {
    // USER HAS DELETED ALL TEXT
    self.post.text = @"#";
    return;
  }

  if ([[self.post.text substringFromIndex:[self.post.text length] - 2] isEqualToString:@"# "])
  {
    self.post.text = [self.post.text substringToIndex:[self.post.text length] - 1];
    return;
  }

  if (self.post.text.length > 1 && [[self.post.text substringFromIndex:[self.post.text length] - 1] isEqualToString:@"#"])
  {
    self.post.text = [self.post.text substringToIndex:[self.post.text length] - 1];
    return;
  }

  if ([[self.post.text substringFromIndex:[self.post.text length] - 2] isEqualToString:@"X "])
  {
    self.post.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.post.text, @"#"];
  }
  else if ([[self.post.text substringFromIndex:[self.post.text length] - 1] isEqualToString:@" "])
  {
    // COMPLETE NEW HASHTAG
    self.post.text = [self.post.text substringToIndex:[self.post.text length] - 1];
    self.post.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.post.text, @" X #"];
  }

  if ([self.post.text rangeOfString:@" X #"].location != NSNotFound)
    [self formatHashtags];
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
  NSRange selectedRange = textView.selectedRange;
  if (selectedRange.location < self.post.text.length)
  {
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *hashTagRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+)[ ]X[ ]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    //  NSMutableArray *ranges = [NSMutableArray new];
    [hashTagRegex enumerateMatchesInString:self.post.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.post.text length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
      NSRange matchedRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
      //    [ranges addObject:selectedRange];
      matchedRange.location = matchedRange.location - 1;
      matchedRange.length = matchedRange.length + 3;
      if (selectedRange.location >= matchedRange.location  && selectedRange.location <= (matchedRange.location + matchedRange.length))
      {
        NSString* part1 = [self.post.text substringToIndex:matchedRange.location];
        NSString* part2 = [self.post.text substringFromIndex:matchedRange.location+matchedRange.length + 1];
        self.post.text = [part1 stringByAppendingString:part2];
      }
    }];

    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(self.post.text.length, 0);
    [self formatHashtags];
  }
}

-(void)formatHashtags
{
  NSMutableAttributedString *originalMutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:self.post.attributedText];
  NSRange originalRange = NSMakeRange(0, originalMutableAttributedString.length);
  [originalMutableAttributedString setAttributes:@{} range:originalRange];
//  [[originalMutableAttributedString mutableString] setString:@""];
  self.post.attributedText = originalMutableAttributedString;


  NSError *error = NULL;
  NSRegularExpression *hashTagRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#(\\w+) X " options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
//  NSMutableArray *ranges = [NSMutableArray new];
  [hashTagRegex enumerateMatchesInString:self.post.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.post.text length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    NSRange selectedRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
//    [ranges addObject:selectedRange];
    selectedRange.location = selectedRange.location - 1;
    selectedRange.length = selectedRange.length + 3;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:self.post.attributedText];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                             value:[UIColor colorWithRed:(173/255.0) green:(173/255.0) blue:(173/255.0) alpha:1]
                             range:selectedRange];
    self.post.attributedText = attributedString;
  }];

  error = NULL;
  NSRegularExpression *xes = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"X[ ]#" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
  //  NSMutableArray *ranges = [NSMutableArray new];
  [xes enumerateMatchesInString:self.post.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.post.text length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    NSRange selectedRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
    //    [ranges addObject:selectedRange];
    selectedRange.length = 1;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:self.post.attributedText];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                             value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:Normalize(35)]
                             range:selectedRange];
    self.post.attributedText = attributedString;
  }];
}
```